# How can I call, pull or extract a single letter or character from a variable consisting of multiple alpha characters that has been sorted via split()?

Tags: python

I am unable to split , slice, list or 'x for x in' a variable - specifically a word using alpha characters that has already been pulled from the split and slice function - into separate letters or characters; please see simple program below. The final 'block' or 'object' of text is where I am running into the issue. Maybe it's just the method or approach that I am using from the start of the whole thing. I just need to print the 1st letter of the 2nd word contained in the "enteredPhrase" variable. It must be utilizing variable text entered by the user. Please help. And thanks in advance. PS I removed my "#" comments.

```
enteredPhrase = input("Enter a phrase or sentence here: ")
print(f"Your phrase or sentence is: {enteredPhrase}")

splitPhrase = enteredPhrase.split()
print(f"The phrase or sentence displayed using the split function in Python: {splitPhrase}")

phraseSize = len(enteredPhrase)
print(f"The size of your phrase or sentence is: {phraseSize}")

secondWord = slice(1, 2)
print(f"The second word in your phrase or sentence is: {splitPhrase[secondWord]}")

finalVariable = splitPhrase[secondWord]
print([x for x in finalVariable])

l = list(finalVariable)
print(l)
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Have you tried printing the value of `finalVariable`?

Comment: Hello He3lixxx! Thank you! Yes, I did try printing "finalVariable" and I just end up with the whole word instead of a single letter or character. I did not get an error.

Comment: Please update your question with an example session with all the outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that using a slice on a `list` gives another `list`. Try this for example, which assigns the value at the 0th index of the result of `splitPhrase[secondWord]` to `finalVariable`:

```py
#enteredPhrase = input("Enter a phrase or sentence here: ")
enteredPhrase = "This sentence is mine."
print(f"Your phrase or sentence is: {enteredPhrase}")

splitPhrase = enteredPhrase.split()
print(f"The phrase or sentence displayed using the split function in Python: {splitPhrase}")

phraseSize = len(enteredPhrase)
print(f"The size of your phrase or sentence is: {phraseSize}")

secondWord = slice(1, 2)
print(f"The second word in your phrase or sentence is: {splitPhrase[secondWord]}")

finalVariable = splitPhrase[secondWord][0]
print([x for x in finalVariable])

l = list(finalVariable)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
Your phrase or sentence is: This sentence is mine.
The phrase or sentence displayed using the split function in Python: ['This', 'sentence', 'is', 'mine.']
The size of your phrase or sentence is: 22
The second word in your phrase or sentence is: ['sentence']
['s', 'e', 'n', 't', 'e', 'n', 'c', 'e']
['s', 'e', 'n', 't', 'e', 'n', 'c', 'e']
```

Another (simpler) way to get to the same result is to skip the slice step and replace `finalVariable = splitPhrase[secondWord][0]` with `finalVariable = splitPhrase[1]`.

Comment: Definitely reading this and going to play around with this. Thank you so much, constantstranger!

Comment: Got it now, thanks! [=

Comment: @cliffjr101 Glad this helped. I also just updated my answer to mention that slice is not actually needed for what your question is trying to accomplish, and to show a simpler approach. Do you need any more help with this?

Comment: That all sounds really great, actually. I'd love to know more. I am trying to understand skipping the slice step with " finalVariable = splitPhrase[secondWord][0] " vs. " finalVariable = splitPhrase[1] "

Comment: splitPhrase is a `list` of `string`s created by the statement `splitPhrase = enteredPhrase.split()`. We know it's a `list` because the docs say so (<https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20split#str.split>). As with any `list`, we can access the value at index `i` like this: `splitPhrase[i]`. In your case, the second string is the one at index `1` (because Python sequence types use 0-offset indexing), so `splitPhrase[1]` gets the second element (a string, in this case) from the `list` returned by the `split()` method of built-in type `str`.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to know. Thanks! It was so much simpler than I was imagining, lol!

Comment: As for `slice()`, the docs here (<https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice>) say: "The slice of s from i to j is defined as the sequence of items with index k such that i <= k < j". The key words here are "sequence of items", which tell us that the return value of a slice operation on a sequence (in our case, a `list`) is another sequence (or `list`). Your slice operation uses the built-in function `slice()`, and happens to create a sequence with only one element. But it's still a `list`, so to get at its single element, we have to use `[0]`L `splitPhrase[secondWord][0]`.

Comment: Sure thing @constantstranger, I am trying to figure out where I can do that. Will this post/thread be saved or archived for future reference?

Comment: I was able to accept your answer, btw.

Comment: This post should remain on the platform indefinitely (unless you or a moderator deletes it).